# Elegant way to aggregate multi-dimensional array by index key

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data

How can I recursively find the total value of all children of an array that looks something like this?

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [value] => ? // 8590.25 + 200.5 + 22.4
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => ? // 8590.25 + 200.5
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 8590.25 // leaf node
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => 200.05 // leaf node
                                    )
                            )

                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 22.4 // leaf node
                    )
             )
    )
```

Comment: Could you provide a `var_export` or plain PHP version of your array: does it have actual `value` and `children` items or are they simply illustrating how the value is to be calculated?

Comment: The actual data is a RecursiveIterator object containing the tree -- I just used an associative array to simplify the problem of "How to recursively aggregate leaf-nodes in a multi-dimensional datatype".. So the specific implementation is not important to me -- I just need an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of case where I'd use a class instead of an array. That way, you can have a getValue () method (or use magic to define the value property using __get), that sums the child values on demand. If you have guarantees that things won't change after a point, you can cache those child sums to avoid repetetive computations. Maybe something like this?

```
class DataStructure
{
  private $children = array ();
  private $value = 0;

  public function __construct ($value = 0)
  {
    $this->value = $value;
  }

  public function getValue ()
  {
    $total = $this->value;
    foreach ($this->children as $child)
    {
      $total += $child->getValue ();
    }
    return $total;
  }

  public function addChild (DataStructure $child)
  {
    $this->children[] = $child;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, the tree is a RecursiveIterator (class DataStructure implements RecursiveIterator), and I'm trying to do the aggregation in a class that extends that DataStructure (class AggregateDatastructure extends DataStructure).. I've gotta look at this stuff some more.. :-P

Comment: Cool. Then I bet you can achieve this by just adding a method or two, once you sort out the details of your implementation. The idea is this: Instead of making one piece of code to iterate through all depths, just ask each child the same thing you've been asked, they'll turn around and ask their children...

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the total sum of the leaf node values:

```
$sum = 0;
array_walk_recursive($arr, create_function('$v, $k, $sum', '$sum[0] += $v;'), array(&$sum));
```

Equivalent using anonymous functions (PHP 5.3+):

```
$sum = 0;
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($v) use (&$sum) { $sum += $v; });
```